# Java testing for folder existance on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, directory, ubuntu-14.04, exists

I have a folder:

```
/home/plattens/workspace/jguids30ma/symbols
```

I am trying to test for its existance in Java:

```
Path objSymbolPath = Paths.get("/home/plattens/workspace/jguids30ma/symbols");
if ( Files.isDirectory(objSymbolPath) != true ) {
    System.out.println("Path is not valid");
}
```

I've tried various options, but so far every variation fails, the test for the directory fails and 'Path is not valid'.

The folder exists.

Comment: Try this if (Files.exists(objSymbolPath)) {sop("exist")}else{sop("not exist")}

Comment: I have tried that, it also fails, I think it may have something to do with the location being in my user space.

Comment: Did you check import package because i tried this code it is working for me i import java.nio.file.Path

Comment: The packages I have imported are: import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

Comment: Did you try creating a folder in your home directory and testing for this?

Comment: Remove io.file package and use only import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

Comment: I can't I need it, why would that be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very odd, just modified the code to this:

```
objSymbolPath = Paths.get(arystrAttr[1]);

if ( clsFolderTest.blnExists(Paths.get("/home/")) != true ) {
    System.out.println("doesn't exist!");
}
if ( clsFolderTest.blnExists(Paths.get("/home/plattens/")) != true ) {
    System.out.println("doesn't exist!");
}
if ( clsFolderTest.blnExists(Paths.get("/home/plattens/workspace/")) != true ) {
    System.out.println("doesn't exist!");
}
if ( clsFolderTest.blnExists(Paths.get("/home/plattens/workspace/jguids30ma/")) != true ) {
    System.out.println("doesn't exist!");
}
if ( clsFolderTest.blnExists(Paths.get("/home/plattens/workspace/jguids30ma/symbols/")) != true ) {
    System.out.println("doesn't exist!");
}
if ( clsFolderTest.blnExists(objSymbolPath) != true ) {
    clsMain.errMessage(clsSymbol.class.toString() + ":alstrToSVG"
                      ,"Symbol path does not exists or is not a folder!");
    return null;                                                            
}
```

All the individual checks with the literal paths work, however the last test still fails, in the end it turns out the the parameter 'arystrAttr' actually had quotes around the path.

Answer (score 0):

I also tested with your code on Ubuntu-14.04 and I got true.

So I think your folder may have some problem.

I think you need to check with "ls -la" command,
and  "d_______r__"  especially r opiton for otherUser..

I hope you find something wrong.

Comment: Result of "ls -la":  "drwxrwxr-x 2 plattens plattens   4096 Feb 12 10:45 symbols"

Comment: Doesn't  it working for the simple folder like /home ?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and compiled. I'm getting correct output so you can refer this code and remove unnecessary import package.

```
package test;

import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path objSymbolPath = Paths.get("/home/admin/Desktop/testing");
        if (Files.isDirectory(objSymbolPath) != true) {
            System.out.println("Path is not valid");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Path is valid");
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it will help you.